# How to change the default Netbeans 7 project directory?

Tags: php, netbeans

This is only a minor annoyance but if I can figure this out I'll be very happy.

Is it possible to change the default project directory in Netbeans 7? I don't know if it's relevant but I have the PHP Netbeans distro.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In new netbeans 7 search file: **D:\Users\YourWindowsUserName\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties**

Delete: **RecentProjectsDisplayNames.**8, **RecentProjectsIcons.**8, **recentProjectsURLs.**8 for cleaning recent projects.

Change **projectsFolder** for default projects folder when creating new one

To find out the location of the projectui.properties file for the latest versions of NetBeans for various operating systems:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Comment: Just an update, as of version 7.2 the netbeans folder is located under C:\Users\<username>\AppData, accessible by typing %appdata% into the start menu search box.

Comment: Strangely for me, this didn't seem to work... I had to reinstall NetBeans and reset the default root project directory from the initial startup screen. It may have been because I was using a special build of NetBeans for a school course.

Answer (score 9):

Under Linux, you can change it in the Netbeans configuration directory: .netbeans/6.8/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties

Answer (score 5):

I believe that Netbeans will remember where your last project was created and uses that as its default. So if you create a project and choose a different directory than the default, then that directory will now be the default.

Comment: This is partly true. When you enter the "Name and Location" section of the new project wizard 'Sources' defaults to a hard coded location, but if I click the browse button next to sources it defaults to the last folder used which is pretty good. I feel like I'm being super anal.

Comment: No you're not. I also would like a way to change it for good. Not just remember last location.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking for how to set the main project so that it runs by default and is debugged by default, then:

**Run > Set Main Project**, and select your project.

This will highlight in bold the name of the folder of your project in the files windows, usually on your the left hand side.

Answer (score 4):

Instructions for Mac, based on some of the answers above:

Make sure NetBeans is closed.

On a Mac, the edit `~/.netbeans/7.0/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties`

Look for a line that starts with `projectsFolder=`

Example:

`projectsFolder=/Users/<your username>/NetBeansProjects`

If this line does not exist, add it with the full path to the directory you want to use.  And of course, if it already exists just edit it to your desired path.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions, right-click on the project you want to move in the 'Projects' tab, and then click 'Move'. This will allow you to move the project to a new directory.

[image: Changing Netbeans Project Folder]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to move the projects in a `Project Group`, then do this:

( I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 )

( I have a `Project Group` based on root directory, and I imported all projects under that directory. )

1. Use Explorer to move (: copy if paranoid :) the projects' directories to the new location.
2. Edit the file `C:\Users\<yourName>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups\<theGroup>.properties`
3. Change the path entry to the new location.
4. Open NetBeans and make sure `Files / Project Groups ...` is looking at the group of projects you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

I use Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7.

For me the projecui.properties file was in `C:\users\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\` directory. About the fourth line down is a property called `projectsFolder`. Just change that to the folder you want and you're done!

Caveat: this is Java, so if you have a backslash, you have to double it up (`C:\folder` would be `C:\\folder`). It seems like I did this before within the application itself, but I could not for the life of me find it. I realize this is an old thread, but it was my first hit googling my problem, so I'm sure others will as well. -Mike

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 it's Users\\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you could find that file in:

```
[%USERPROFILE%|$Env:UserProfile]\.netbeans\...\projectui.properties
```

Found this, http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir, but did not have success with it.  Neither the command line value nor netbeans_default_userdir from netbeans.conf were persisted to projectui.properties.