# Getting "NOT FOUND" error when runngin zend framework project using NetBeans 

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans6.8

I followed tutorial on http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/zend-framework-screencast.html, but I am getting not found error whenever I try to run the project.

When I check the box "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location" while creating project and enter path to Apache2/htdocs, it works fine. I am just curious why I need to do that ? why can't the run command automatically deploy the project on the server ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing but you must run your projects from htdocs. So if you put your site somewhere else like my documents it will not work.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266792/how-to-change-the-default-netbeans-6-7-project-directory) for information about the default folder for projects.