# How to set a default directory for NetBeans PHP projects?

Tags: php, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the default Netbeans 6.7 project directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266792/how-to-change-the-default-netbeans-6-7-project-directory)

I have installed the Netbeans, and I'm trying to make a new project - the system suggests me to install in /var/www folder, but I've made a new folder for it /home/myuser/myprojects, and I want that this folder will be a default. So, please, tell me, where can I change default folder? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you peak at the settings and see if anything maybe jumped out at you?

Comment: Yes I did, but I haven't found anything

Comment: I mean, is it the Java SE/EE versions?  C/C++? PHP? All in one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17352/discussion-between---and-jared-farrish)