# How to change the default Netbeans 8.0.2 project directory?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

I installed XAMPP and then Netbeans and noticed that new PHP projects default to XAMPP's `htdocs` folder. Does anyone know how to change this default folder?

I tried to search google but all the first page results are related to Netbeans 7. I tried to follow the instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266792/how-to-change-the-default-netbeans-7-project-directory) but I can't find the `projectui.properties` mentioned in the accepted answer. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will help you

1. Edit the file `C:\Users\<YourName>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups\<TheGroup>.properties`.
2. Change the path entry to the new location.

Comment: Here is a solution Netbeans 8.1+ https://medium.com/@codeliger/changing-default-sources-folder-in-netbeans-a2c5355cdc03

Answer (score 3):

In addition to directory given in above answer, default directory under NetBeans 10 and Linux/Ubuntu can be modified using

```
nano ~/.netbeans/10.0/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, its parent folder becomes a default folder for your future project, you can reassign it everytime creating new project.

Comment: Try providing more detailed answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit that file if you are using NetBeans IDE 15 and installed from Snap Store.

```
sudo nano ~/snap/netbeans/69/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Running Netbeans 11:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_WINDOWS_USER>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties
```

Look for this property:

[image]